# Problems with AJAX, DOM and <option> tag

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dom

After lots of hours trying to find a solution, I could not find the problem in my code.
I´m trying to get some info about the user like favourites dates and this kind of thing. To do that, I send some dates that my program create with select  tag. First of all I call to an ajax function that brings me back the option tags. When my option boxes are loaded, then I wait the user to change it with the click in the button. Then, I want to send the information back to the server. That´s clear, but the problem is that the DOM, loaded at the beginning all the content that was inside. That means, when it started loading, there was no option item id. I tried to use the .live() JQUERY command but there are not results, no alert messages are shown. I tried with everything and nothing works. Here it´s the JQUERY syntax.

```
 $('#Consultar3').live('click', function(){         
      var Date1 = $('#combo1 option:selected').attr("value");
      alert($('#combo1 option:selected').attr("value"));
 });
```

and this is my php file that content all the  tags.

```
 for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++){
        $variable_Provider = new UIProvider;
        $value = $variable_Provider->GetDate();
        $j=1;
        $print.='<select id=combo'.$i.'; style="width:110; height:25">';
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($value)){ 
            $print.='<option value='.$row[1].'>'.$row[0].'</option>\n';  
            $j++;
        } 
        $print.="</select><br>"; 
    }
    $print.='Caja<input id="combo3"; type="text" value="1" style="width:150; height:25"><br>';
    $print.='<input id="Consultar3" type="button" value="Consultar" style="width:110; height:25"><br>';
```

Anyone could guess what is the problem?

Comment: You generate combo0 and combo1, but hardcode the live stuff on combo1 only?

Comment: please note, the live() function is deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/live/ This is not going to help your question, but it may help you in the future.

Comment: also, in your php code, you never set the $print variable initially... this would create a php error.

Comment: is this code exactly what you have in the page that isn't working? As @MarcB mentions, you have hardcoded the action to the second option. Also, in your for loop you instantiate 'j', but don't use it. And, you are giving the value attribute `$row[1]`, but the display is `$row[0]`. Also, you attached the live even to an element with ID of `Consultar3`, are you sure your DOM is correct?

Comment: I´m sorry because I didn´t copy in my code the $print inicializated but it is! just like $print=""; in the first line of my code. About the j, It´s useless yes, I just deleted it. I will copy directly all the code I have.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found my problem in the combo definition and in the DOM way to call the combo:

```
$('#Consultar3').live('click', function(){          
  var Date1 = $('#combo0 option:selected').attr("value");
  var Date1 = $('#combo1 option:selected').attr("value");
  $("#Statistics_Primitiva").load("../ajax/Estadisticas.php",{Control_Var:2, Date0:Date0, Date1:Date1});
});    

$print.='<select id=combo'.$i.'; style="width:110; height:25">';
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($value)){ 
    $print.='<option value='.$row[1].'>'.$row[0].'</option>\n';  
}
```

the problem was in the